# It goes to the next after executing 'return'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, telegram

Hi I'm developing a telegram alarm bot and it print the result after `return`

Here is my code:

```
import FinanceDataReader as fdr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import date
import sys
fdr.__version__
import schedule
import time
import pytz
from numpyencoder import NumpyEncoder
import json
import telegram


def job():
    now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Seoul'))
    today = date.today()
    weekend = today.weekday()
    print(weekend)
    # 예외시간 설정. 9시 이전 및 15시 이후, 주말에는 알람을 보내지 않음
    if now and weekend == [5, 6]:
        return
    # 봇 설정
    API_KEY = 'My API KEY'
    bot = telegram.Bot(token=API_KEY)
    public_chat_name = '@MarketTimer_alarm_bot'
    
    # 코스닥지수
    code = 'KQ11'
    df = fdr.DataReader('KQ11','2022-08').reset_index()
    # 3,5,10 이동평균 딕셔너리에 할당
    df['close_sma3d'] = df['Close'].rolling(3).mean()
    df['close_sma5d'] = df['Close'].rolling(5).mean()
    df['close_sma10d'] = df['Close'].rolling(10).mean()
    # dataframe 재구성
    df2 = df.loc[: ,['Date','Close', 'close_sma3d','close_sma5d','close_sma10d']].iloc[-1:]
    alerts = df2[(df2['Close'] > df2['close_sma3d']) | (df2['Close'] > df2['close_sma5d']) | (df2['Close'] > df2['close_sma10d'])]
    alerts2 = df2[(df2['Close'] < df2['close_sma3d']) | (df2['Close'] < df2['close_sma5d']) | (df2['Close'] < df2['close_sma10d'])]

    for index, row in alerts.iterrows():
        z = row['Close']
        a = round(row['close_sma3d'], 2)
        b = round(row['close_sma5d'], 2)
        c = round(row['close_sma10d'], 2)
            # telegram 알람에서 출력하기 위해 datetime64만 json str 형식으로 변환
        row['Date'] = row['Date'].date()
        jsonstr1 = json.dumps(str(row['Date']))
        Market_timing = (f"{jsonstr1} 현재가가 3 or 5 or 10 단순이동평균보다 높습니다 코스닥_현재가 {z} 3일이동평균 {a} 5일이동평균 {b} 10일이동평균 {c}")
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id = public_chat_name, text=Market_timing).chat_id

    for index, row in alerts2.iterrows():
        z = row['Close']
        a = round(row['close_sma3d'], 2)
        b = round(row['close_sma5d'], 2)
        c = round(row['close_sma10d'], 2)
        # telegram 알람에서 출력하기 위해 datetime64만 json str 형식으로 변환
        row['Date'] = row['Date'].date()
        jsonstr1 = json.dumps(str(row['Date']))
        Market_timing2 = (f"{jsonstr1} 현재가가 3 and 5 and 10 단순이동평균보다 낮습니다 코스닥_현재가 {z} 3일이동평균 {a} 5일이동평균 {b} 10일이동평균 {c}")
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id = public_chat_name, text=Market_timing2).chat_id

schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("12:00").do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("18:31").do(job)

print('Start App..')

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

And here is the result, I get the right alarm in my telegram app also.

```
Start App..
5
```

It seems like it executed `return` so it printed `5`, but why does it goes to the next and execute the rest of thing?

to help you, I got the alarm for this.

```
Market_timing2 = (f"{jsonstr1} 현재가가 3 and 5 and 10 단순이동평균보다 낮습니다 코스닥_현재가 {z} 3일이동평균 {a} 5일이동평균 {b} 10일이동평균 {c}")
```

Comment: Could you dig into `weekend == [5, 6]`?

Comment: try `weekend in [5, 6]`

Comment: ` while weekend >= 5: ` works